# C# Разбить строку с параметрами запроса в ассоциативный массив

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Дана форма `<input type="hidden" name="requestParams"/>`

Jquery передает в нее данные из формы (параметры для запроса, пишутся вручную в форме). Нужно обработать строку с параметрами запроса, и поместить ключ => значение в `Dictionary<string, string>` для построения HTTP запроса с параметрами, только не пойму как это можно сделать, т.к. в Dictionary добавляются все значения подряд.

Строка с параметрами выглядит так: `count=100&user_id=100500`

Код:

```
        // Разбиваю строку по символу & и Перебираю полученный массив
        foreach (var param in Request.Form["requestParams"].Split(new string[] { "&" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        {
            // Разбиваю строку по символу = и перебираю полученный массив
            foreach (var data in param.Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Request param: " + data);
            }
        }
```

На выходе получается:

`Request param: count
 Request param: 100
 Request param: user_id
 Request param: 100500`

Поместить эти значения в Dictionary не получится, т.к. перебор идет и по ключам и по значениям сразу...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы изобретаете велосипед. Имеет смысл использовать [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx). Он и раскодирует закодированные значения правильно.

Если очень уж хочется велосипед, то пишите

```
var parts = param.Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var key = parts[0];
var value = parts[1];
dict[key] = value;
```

Но этот код намного хуже, потому что не проверяет ошибки и не декодирует закодированные строки.